# Homestead: How would I map multiple domains to the same path?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, homestead

I was wondering how one would assign multiple domains to the same path in Homestead/Vagrant?

This is basically what I want, but it does not work.. When I attempt this, I can't access the server at all.

```
sites:
    - map: main-url.app, sub.main-url.app, another-domain.app
      to: /Code/Laravel/public
```

And same goes when I attempt without commas.

```
sites:
    - map: main-url.app sub.main-url.app another-domain.app
      to: /Code/Laravel/public
```

Any help? - Maybe this is not possible without creating multiple sites?

Thanks

Comment: By "same path" i mean to same site, as in Homestead site.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but how about

```
sites:
    - map: main-url.app
      to: /Code/Laravel/public
    - map: sub.main-url.app
      to: /Code/Laravel/public
    - map: another-domain.app
      to: /Code/Laravel/public
```

Comment: Yeah I could do that, I just have around 8-9 mappings for the same path and I'd rather keep it in a single site :)

Answer (score -3):

run the `vagrant provision` terminal command from your Homestead directory.

Comment: This answer defiantly does not deserve a downvote. Point of answer: Remember to run "homestead halt && homestead up --provision" after changing homestead.yaml file, to ensure changes take effect. That was the issue for me. Thanks @wedojava